# How do I change the default document margins in docxjs

Tags: javascript, docx

I'm using the [DOCXJS](https://docx.js.org/#/) library and was wondering if it was possible to reduce the default document margins.

I found that the docs briefly [mention](https://docx.js.org/#/usage/sections?id=sections) that you can alter margins of sections, though they don't explain how.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed it by checking out the [demos](https://github.com/dolanmiu/docx/blob/master/demo/6-page-borders.ts). The syntax that should be used is:

```
const doc = new Document({
sections: [
    {
        properties: {
            page: {
                margin: {
                    top: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    bottom: 0,
                    left: 0,
                },
            },
        },
        children: [new docx.Paragraph({text:"Hello World!"})],
    },
],
```

});

Comment: What are the units of these margin values? They don't seem to be pixels or any other standard unit of measure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are DXA values which are 1/20th of a point which is 1/72 of an inch. Hope this helped!

Comment: not sure what the measurement units are however I can tell you the number 5 gives you a margin of 1mm.